# What is gsub(/(\d{4})\/(\d\d)\/(\d\d)\/(.*)/, '\1-\2-\3-\4') mean?

Tags: ruby, regex

I've stumbled upon this on ruby code.
I know \d{4})\/(\d\d)\/(\d\d)\/(.*)/ means but what is \1-\2-\3-\4 means?

Comment: Someone is a big backslash fan. What's wrong with `%r[(\d{4})/(\d\d)/(\d\d)/(.*)]` instead of `/(\d{4})\/(\d\d)\/(\d\d)\/(.*)/`?

Comment: @Jörg: The author probably didn't know about `%r` regex literals.

Comment: I'm new to ruby so I have no idea what you guys talking about but it seem %r[(\d{4})/(\d\d)/(\d\d)/(.*)] is cleaner for me too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `\1-\2-\3-\4` are [back references](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) to the captured data within the regex itself.

So `\1` contains the data that was captured in the first group, `\2` was the data captured in the second group, `\3` was the data captured in the 3rd group and so on.

See here for the [Ruby implementation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html)

Answer (score 3):

Those are backreferences. \1 means the result of the first group of brackets `()`, ie `(\d\d)`, \2 means the 2nd group and so on.

Answer (score 1):

transform `1234/12/12/XX` into `1234-12-12-XX`

Comment: what `gsub(/(\d{4})\/(\d\d)\/(\d\d)\/(.*)/, '\1-\2-\3-\4')` actually does. `1234/12/12/XX` is just a sample input

Comment: Ah, ok.  Your original answer didn't make a whole lot of sense.

Answer (score 0):

I think the \1,\2 etc just referer to the matched groups

i.e. \1 == (\d{4})

Answer (score 0):

They refer back to the matched groups (substituion backreferences)

For more info, see http://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html

Answer (score -1):

You can capture parts of the pattern of the regular expression by placing them inside parentheses and then on the substitution part reference them with \1,\2,\3,... according to the order they appear.

In your example \1 will be the first 4 digits, \2 will be the second two, \3 will be the following two and \4 will be the rest.

So "20100410milk" will be substituted by "2010-04-10-milk", because \1 will be 2010, \2 04, \3 10 and \4 milk.

Comment: You've missed the literal slashes in the input.